# Is the voltage drop smaller in three-phase circuits?

Tags: voltage

If the same power and the same distance are used for a single-phase and a three-phase circuit. Will the voltage drop of the three-phase circuit be smaller?

Comment: Depends on the conductor size. Are they equal in your example?

Comment: Yes, let's say both are 2.5mm.

Comment: What about the voltages? Do we assume one phase of the three phase electricity is equal to the single phase voltage?

Comment: This, for example, a single-phase motor and a three-phase motor. With the same potency.

Comment: Since the current is shared across the three phases, the voltage drop will be less.

Comment: Okay, is that I was calculating the voltage drop in a project. And there were very similar distances and powers and those that were powered by three-phase circuits had a lower voltage drop.

Comment: If all the other parameters are equal, conductor size and length, load power, power factor and input (phase) voltage then the voltage drop over the length of the conductors will be less in the 3 phase case. Change any one of the other parameters and all bets are off.

Comment: What is your single-phase voltage?  What is your phase-phase voltage in 3-phase?  Seems likely that the 3-phase will be more efficient simply because it is higher voltage, all other issues aside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the power transmission efficiency will be higher for a three-phase circuit compared to a single-phase circuit because three wires are used instead of two. The transmission line can be designed for lower voltage drop using the same size for each of the three-phase wires as for each of the single-phase wires. The three-phase transmission line could also be designed to save copper rather than save energy.

If the transmission line supplies motor loads, three-phase motors can be used rather than single phase motors. Three phase motors have the advantage of dividing the current three ways, so that provides one similar savings opportunity. Three-phase motors have an additional saving opportunity in their ability to more simply provide a revolving magnetic field.

Rectifiers are another load device that is improved bu using three-phase power. Their un-filtered output has much less ripple voltage than single-phase rectifiers.